# Is it possible to establish a local network between specific Ethereum accounts within the same operational system using Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, geth-clique, local-blockchain

I tried to launch a local network using Geth. I mean a network of just one running system that hosts some Ethereum accounts. I did that by the below config file and the below command to run Geth node. But whenever I try to transfer ETH between accounts of this network, Geth throws this error:

```
 err="transaction indexing is in progress"
```

Although I unlocked all accounts and try `miner.start()` on the miner's (signer's) Geth JavaScript Console but this error is not eliminated.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to establish a local network between specific Ethereum accounts within the same operational system using Geth?
2. How can I eliminate the error  `err="transaction indexing is in progress"` when I try transfer ETH.
3. According to this guide, whenever we try `miner.start()` it should return `true`. But it returns `null` for me, why?

Genesis:

```
{

      "config":{
  
         "chainId":1408,
  
         "homesteadBlock":0,
  
         "eip158Block":0,
  
         "eip155Block":0,
  
         "eip150Block":0,
  
         "byzantiumBlock":0,
  
         "constantinopleBlock":0,
  
         "petersburgBlock":0,
  
         "istanbulBlock":0,
  
         "berlinBlock":0,
  
         "londonBlock":0,
  
         "eip5133Block":0,
         "clique": {
                         "period": 3,
                   "epoch": 28800
             },
         "homesteadGas":0,
  
         "eip158Gas":0,
      
         "eip155Gas":0,
      
         "eip150Gas":0,
      
         "byzantiumGas":0,
      
         "constantinopleGas":0,
      
         "petersburgGas":0,
      
         "istanbulGas":0,
      
         "berlinGas":0,
      
         "londonGas":0,
      
         "eip5133Gas":0
     },
  
     "difficulty":"0x64",
  
     "gasLimit":"0x6ACFC0",
  
     "extradata":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b865ca35c149dfaad9f5a76a0fc285bc7d8501d70000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  
     "alloc":{
     "0xb865ca35c149dfaad9f5a76a0fc285bc7d8501d7":{"balance":"100000000000000000000"},
     "0xf904d0fdf22d13befab481c937ee5b2745268351":{"balance":"100000000000000000000"},
     "0x2ade5a95753dd9dd2ac2ada40f5f7680476ac2c3":{"balance":"100000000000000000000"},
     "0xe7ea3159429c09b1857d2a7e18bd94e15f65cb49":{"balance":"100000000000000000000"},
     "0x22f15682564f88deed3d90992495bf241e852e58":{"balance":"100000000000000000000"}
     }
  
  }
```

The command to run Geth client:

```
geth --datadir C:\...\localEthereum --identity "localEthereum" --networkid 1408 --port 30300 --netrestrict 127.0.0.1/32  --nat extip:127.0.0.1 --ws --allow-insecure-unlock --ws.addr 127.0.0.1 --ws.port 8552 --ws.api eth,net,web3,personal,admin,miner --ws.origins "*" --mine --miner.etherbase 0xb865ca35c149dfaad9f5a76a0fc285bc7d8501d7
```

The Geth console when I run it and try an ETH sending:

```
INFO [03-06|16:54:24.689] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 total=50
INFO [03-06|16:54:24.869] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000
INFO [03-06|16:54:24.870] Initializing the KZG library             backend=gokzg
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.141] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=154.00MiB dirty=256.00MiB
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.143] Using pebble as the backing database
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.143] Allocated cache and file handles         database=C:\...\localEthereum\geth\chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=8192
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.500] Opened ancient database                  database=C:\...\localEthereum\geth\chaindata\ancient/chain readonly=false
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.501] State scheme set to already existing     scheme=hash
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.581] Initialising Ethereum protocol           network=1408 dbversion=8
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.606]
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.606] ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.606] Chain ID:  1408 (unknown)
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.606] Consensus: Clique (proof-of-authority)
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.607]
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.607] Pre-Merge hard forks (block based):
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.607]  - Homestead:                   #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/homestead.md)
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.607]  - Tangerine Whistle (EIP 150): #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/tangerine-whistle.md)
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.607]  - Spurious Dragon/1 (EIP 155): #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/spurious-dragon.md)
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.607]  - Spurious Dragon/2 (EIP 158): #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/spurious-dragon.md)
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.608]  - Byzantium:                   #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/byzantium.md)
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.608]  - Constantinople:              #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/constantinople.md)
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.608]  - Petersburg:                  #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/petersburg.md)
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.608]  - Istanbul:                    #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/istanbul.md)
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.608]  - Berlin:                      #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/berlin.md)
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.608]  - London:                      #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/london.md)
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.608]
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.608] The Merge is not yet available for this network!
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.609]  - Hard-fork specification: https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/paris.md
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.609]
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.609] Post-Merge hard forks (timestamp based):
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.609]
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.610] ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.610]
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.624] Loaded most recent local block           number=0 hash=c957e6..aaa6e6 td=100 age=54y11mo2w
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.626] Initialized transaction indexer          range="last 2350000 blocks"
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.627] Setting new local account                address=0x22F15682564f88DEED3d90992495bf241e852e58
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.628] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=1 dropped=0
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.638] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=1 accounts=1
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.683] Enabled snap sync                        head=0 hash=c957e6..aaa6e6
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.701] Gasprice oracle is ignoring threshold set threshold=2
WARN [03-06|16:54:25.757] Engine API enabled                       protocol=eth
WARN [03-06|16:54:25.757] Engine API started but chain not configured for merge yet
INFO [03-06|16:54:25.757] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/localEthereum/v1.13.11-stable-8f7eb9cc/windows-amd64/go1.21.6
ERROR[03-06|16:54:26.051] Bootstrap node filtered by netrestrict   id=c845e51a5e470e44 ip=18.138.108.67
ERROR[03-06|16:54:26.052] Bootstrap node filtered by netrestrict   id=f23ac6da7c02f84a ip=3.209.45.79
ERROR[03-06|16:54:26.052] Bootstrap node filtered by netrestrict   id=ef2d7ab886910dc8 ip=65.108.70.101
ERROR[03-06|16:54:26.052] Bootstrap node filtered by netrestrict   id=6b36f791352f15eb ip=157.90.35.166
INFO [03-06|16:54:26.057] New local node record                    seq=1,709,728,632,820 id=74d1dd4243b4cdab ip=127.0.0.1
 udp=30300 tcp=30300
INFO [03-06|16:54:26.077] Started P2P networking                   self=enode://3f5b006ce6db06a63f277fd6af72f89fdae9503733125af3aaacf58346e741e136fb50f800599cf7ebf89e68f248cd24a3a1c4c2aea83a7fe64300eaae2b1f76@127.0.0.1:30300
INFO [03-06|16:54:26.118] IPC endpoint opened                      url=\\.\pipe\geth.ipc
INFO [03-06|16:54:26.119] Loaded JWT secret file                   path=C:\...\localEthereum\geth\jwtsecret crc32=0xa77eecb6
INFO [03-06|16:54:26.120] WebSocket enabled                        url=ws://127.0.0.1:8552
INFO [03-06|16:54:26.230] WebSocket enabled                        url=ws://127.0.0.1:8551
INFO [03-06|16:54:26.230] HTTP server started                      endpoint=127.0.0.1:8551 auth=true prefix= cors=localhost vhosts=localhost
INFO [03-06|16:54:26.231] Legacy pool tip threshold updated        tip=0
INFO [03-06|16:54:26.231] Legacy pool tip threshold updated        tip=1,000,000,000
INFO [03-06|16:54:26.231] Snap sync complete, auto disabling
INFO [03-06|16:54:26.232] Commit new sealing work                  number=1 sealhash=6ede2f..be72a8 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed=0s
WARN [03-06|16:54:26.232] Block sealing failed                     err="authentication needed: password or unlock"
WARN [03-06|16:55:54.970] Served eth_sendTransaction               reqid=fb9ff272-eb10-44b7-9f73-48bfcc9bfde2 duration=318.0394ms err="already known"
INFO [03-06|16:58:44.466] Setting new local account                address=0xf904D0FDF22D13BEfAb481c937ee5b2745268351
INFO [03-06|16:58:44.503] Submitted transaction                    hash=0x5204d3a88002b51a7aea1ed73ef629d9d1e2435f10dfc58ebf43227cdb928a0c from=0xf904D0FDF22D13BEfAb481c937ee5b2745268351 nonce=1 recipient=0xB865cA35C149DFaad9f5A76A0fc285Bc7D8501D7 value=1,000,000,000,000,000,000
WARN [03-06|16:58:44.606] Served eth_getTransactionReceipt         reqid=8e8cd4e2-fe69-4243-a1b4-31a9decd763c duration=82.5298ms  err="transaction indexing is in progress" errdata="transaction indexing is in progress"
```